# Как удобнее всего сделать структуру в битриксе?

Tags: битрикс

Добрый вечер! Подскажите как можно удобно реализовать структуру ЖК(жилого комплекса)?

Структура: Комплекс - Секция - Этаж - Квартиры

Не хочется плодить по 20 этажей у каждой секции и у каждого этажа по несколько квартир, с учетом того что большинство повторяются.

Параметры квартиры: метраж, цена, доступность(свободна или бронь),этаж, секция.

Может кто делал нечто подобное?

Заранее благодарю!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обычно делаю такую структуру — с 4 инфоблоками:

1. ЖК (название, изображения)
2. Дом с привязкой к ЖК (тут уже хранится материал, кол-во этажей, адрес и т.д.)
3. Планировка с привязкой к дому (площади, планировка, цена и т.д.)
4. Квартира с привязкой к планировке (этаж, статус, номер квартиры)

Comment: Привязка идет свойством по элементу? Планировки и квартиры разбиваешь как-то по разделам или они все вместе скопом идут? Выводишь все это дело каталогом? Фильтрация нормально будет работать?

Comment: И как при такой структуре вы ЧПУ организовываете?

Comment: /жк/дом/{номер квартиры}или{количество комнат-площадь-этаж}

Comment: Делается простой комплексный компонент в котором проверяется путь и выбирается соответствующий файл шаблона, а в нём уже подключается нужный компонент для списка, жк, дома или квартиры

Comment: Спасибо, на самом деле не сталкивался c написанием комплексного компонента, но я так понимаю он должен быть похож на компонент catalog?

Comment: и правильно я понимаю что сначала я должен вывести квартиры через   CIBlockElement::GetList а потом по свойству привязки вытаскивать другие параметры из инфоблоков?

Comment: По поводу комплексного компонента — его главная задача определить какая страница шаблона должна быть подключена, а на нажной странице уже подключаются нужные компонента. Как пример можно использовать или news или catalog.